# subprocess.Popen is creating two processes instead of one

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, kill

I am creating a subprocess using this line of code:

`p = subprocess.Popen(["doesItemExist.exe", id], shell=False)`

and when I run the script while I have the Task Manager open, I can see that it creates two processes and not one. The issue is that when I go to kill it, it kills one (using p.kill()), but not the other. I've tried looking online but the only examples I find are about shell=True and their solutions don't work for me. I've confirmed that that line only gets called once.

What can I do? Popen is only giving me back the one pid so I don't understand how to get the other so I can kill both.

Comment: does the second process also appear when you execute the program by double clicking?

Comment: Ah, running it does create a second process too. When I exit out, though, both get closed. The second process only stays open when I run it as a subprocess by the main script

Comment: It could be that killing the process doesn't let it properly clean itself up. Shouldn't you be using `terminate` and not `kill` anyway? `kill` seems like it would only be necessary if the process did not respond to `terminate`.

Comment: @RandomDavis terminate has the same issue. It cleans up one and not the other.

Comment: Is the process a GUI or a console application? How is it closed normally? Is it maybe the spawned process that kills the parent process, but you're trying to kill the spawned process? Maybe if that's the case you could get the children of the process you spawned and try terminating/killing those?

Comment: It is a console process. The main script closes as soon as it finishes its task and after waiting for the spawned process to be killed. The issue is that Popen is creating two processes but only giving me back the one pid. Is there a way for me to get both of those pids that were spawned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to deal with this issue by creating a clean up function which just uses the following:

`subprocess.run(["taskkill", "/IM", "doesItemExist.exe", "/F"], shell=True)`

This will kill any leftover tasks. If anyone uses this, be careful that your exe has a unique name to prevent you from killing anything you don't mean to. If you want to hide the output/errors, just set the stdout and stderr to subprocess.PIPE.

Also, if there is no process to kill it will report that as an error.